# Заменить клавишу fn на win

Tags: windows, клавиатура, железо

На клавиатуре справа вместо клавиши <kbd>win</kbd> сделана клавиша <kbd>fn</kbd>.
**Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы эта <kbd>fn</kbd> работала как <kbd>win</kbd>?**

Клавиатура: A4TECH KLS-7MUU.
OC: Windows 11.

[image: картинка клавиатуры]

Comment: Хотел предложить классический вариант со сменой раскладки клавиатуры, но люди пишут, что клавиша [Fn не имеет скан-кода](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423724/)  (

Comment: @Daemon-5, меня в первую очередь интересуют win (который тут fn) + right ctrl + стрелка.

Comment: На некоторых ноутбуках в BIOS есть функция ремапа (у меня, по крайней мере), продвинутые клавиатуры, поддерживающие ремап в своих настройках, тоже это позволяют сделать. В случае вашей клавы - увы, не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте PowerToys. Вот здесь можно почитать:

[Как создать кнопку Win, если у вас её нет](https://zawindows.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-win-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82/)

100% гарантии, к сожалению, нет, не со всеми клавами корректно работает.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Не работает. Нажатие fn не определяется как клавиша.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, вроде нормальный ответ - название-то есть.

Comment: Да, с одной стороны «fn» вроде как полезная примочка, с другой стороны оказалась проблемной…